# How to call the function within the other function using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

i have a parent component within which i call a function to return jsx.

below is my code,

```
const Parent: React.FC<Props> = () =>{
    const renderIcon = () => {
        if (!condition1 || !condition2) {
            return null;
    }

    if (icon_name==='add') {
        return count === 0 ? null : (
            <firstdiv> //repeated code
                <seconddiv>
                    <Icon name={icon_name} />
                </seconddiv>
            </firstdiv>
       ); 
    } else {
        return (
            <firstdiv> //repeated code
                <seconddiv>
                    <Icon name={icon_name} />
                </seconddiv>
            </firstdiv>
        );
    }


    return (
        {renderIcon()}
    );
}
```

Now i added one more function to refactor the repeated code like below

```
const renderAnother = () => {
    return (
        <firstdiv>
            <seconddiv>
                <Icon name={icon_name} />
            </seconddiv>
        </firstdiv>
    );
}


const renderIcon = () => {
        if (!condition1 || !condition2) {
            return null;
    }

    if (icon_name==='add') {
        return count === 0 ? null : renderAnother();
    } else {
        return renderAnother();
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work...how do i call renderAnotherIcon function within renderIcon function. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: can you please reproduce this on codesandbox. That way it would be more helpful for us to understand your question.

Comment: typo `renderAnotherIcon` vs `renderAnother`

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the code a bit more, returning null when none of the conditions are matched:

```
const renderIcon = () => {
  if (!condition1 || !condition2 || (icon_name === 'add' && count === 0)) {
    return null;
  }
  return renderAnother();
}
```